# JIRA description's editor disappeared

Tags: editor, jira

I have a strange issue that I'm unable to resolve in Jira settings or find any information online.

Running JIRA Cloud.

The editor for the Description field is all of a sudden missing editing controls.  See attached image.  Screenshot is from JIRA that I edited, not from our instance.  I feel like we had it couple of weeks ago and I just didn't notice it and all of a sudden it is now GONE.

Any ideas if it's a setting or add-on??
[image]

**This is our editor:**

[image]

In addition, the comment renderer used to render @Person links as **Person Name** blue link, and now it just displays it as [~Person] plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the *description* and *comment* fields on your JIRA are configured with the plain text renderer instead of the wiki renderer.

If you're a jira administrator, you can go to *Field Configurations*, then click *Configure* for the *Default Field Configuration* (or any others you may have). Now look for the *description* or *comment* fields and check which renderer is configured for them.

[More documentation available here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiracloud/configuring-renderers-776636458.html).

Comment: Perfect, that was it!  And now I know how it happened.  I never had a field configuration or field configuration screen.  Then went to remove Resolution field from some default screens.  That automatically created a Default Field Configuration and somehow that Default Field Configuration had renderers set to Default Text.  So I changed DESCRIPTION and COMMENT to render with Wiki.  Thank you!